# SubSonic MySQL Version

Tags: mysql, subsonic

SubSonic 2.2 requires MySQL Connector 5.3.2.0. This is not included in the download package, nor is it any longer available from the MySQL download site.

I know I can build SubSonic again from source to get around this, but this is a pain.

Can someone on the SubSonic project please change the "Specific Version" flag on the MySQL assembly reference to "false"?

Comment: I think this is not a question for the "forums", more like an issue to be submitted here: http://code.google.com/p/subsonicproject/issues/list

Answer (score 0):

Change the "Specific Version" Attribute isn't a wise solution.
The linked version should have passed the subsonic unit tests, so it should be ok.
From my own experience I know that mysql sometimes changes the behaviour of the assembly (e.g. a returnvalue 0 or 1 suddenly changes to true/false) that's why we are stuck with an old 5.1.2.2 version (we have no unit test's ;(  for our old core)

But if you "tweak" the download link:

http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-Net/mysql-connector-net-5.2.3.zip/from/http://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/misc/mysql/

you should still be able to download the old connector. If not, you can drop me a line. I still have the msi and the binaries archived.